# Fullscreen video without black borders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem I have is that the video always gets black bars on the sides or on the top/bottom depending on the screen size.

[image]

*Any idea how to get it full screen always without showing that annoying black bars?* and without using a plugin.

This is my markup:

```html
    <div id="full-bg">
        <div class="box iframe-box" width="1280" height="800">
            <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/67794477?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=0fb0d4" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
    #full-bg{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        img{
            display: none;
        }
        .iframe-box{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            background: url(../img/fittobox.png);
            left: 0 !important;
            top: 0 !important;
            iframe{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it depends on your vid format and it's size. you can try stretching it, but then your video may look weird

Comment: If the aspect ratio of your video doesn't match the aspect ratio of your monitor, it *should* have black bars.

Comment: That is to make the video display at the correct aspect ratio, which is controlled by the video software (Flash I'm guessing?), not JavaScript or CSS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding to your CSS

```css
.iframe-box {
    max-width: 1280px; /* video width */
    max-height: 720px; /* video height */
}
```

This means that `width: 100%; height: 100%` will let the element will expand as much as it can, until it hits a maximum height or width of `720px` or `1280px`, respectively.

If the screen you're viewing it on has a greater resolution, the node will stop expanding and you'll not have black borders.

---

Further, afaik the following is not valid CSS, are you using a library or something?

```css
#full-bg {
    .iframe-box {
        foo: bar;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit after answer accepted:** I just thought of a completely different way to achieve this, but it would require you to change a lot of your CSS

```css
.fittobox {                /* give fit to box an aspect ratio */
    display: inline-block; /* let it be styled thusly */
    padding: 0;            /* get rid of pre-styling */
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;           /* take up full width available */
    padding-top: 56.25%;   /* give aspect ratio of 16:9; "720 / 1280 = 0.5625" */
    height: 0px;           /* don't want it to expand beyond padding */
    position: relative;    /* allow for absolute positioning of child elements */
}

.fittobox > iframe {
    position: absolute;    /* expand to fill */
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: **Edit After Update Works** and the `code can be modified easily`

Comment: it's hiding video controllers

Answer (score 1):

If you know the aspect ratio of your video, you shouldn't even need Javascript. You can use a percentage-based `padding-top`.

I could post code, but I'd recommend you read [this entire article](http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

@Paul S. 's answer works for me for the `.fittobox` container for 16:9 video aspect ratios but the `.fittobox > iframe` embed still has black bars with his CSS. Removing the right and bottom positioning fixes it for me (no need for "px" in those 0 values, of course):

```
.fittobox > iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```