# Fullscreen html page and fullscreen video without black borders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I've this html:

```
<div id="container">
  <video id="video" src="video.ogv" loop></video>
</div>
```

Div "container" and video fills all screen

```
#container {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px:
   left: 0px;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;  
}

#container video {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px:
   left: 0px;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;  
}
```

The monitor where I'm testing is 1920x1080 while video is 1280x720: obviously I obtain two black border (top and bottom).

How can I view video without borders and without stretching it?

I've already search on so, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984326/fullscreen-video-without-black-borders), but is not my case.

## Edit

I had forgotten min-width: and min-height proprerties, as HoangHieu suggest!

CSS become:

```
#container video {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use properties : min-width: and min-height:

Comment: don't forget max-width and max-height.